# Redirected To Homepage When Using "www."

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove the www. from the front of my URL so I added the following code to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Which worked fine, but when people go to www.example.com/example it redirects them to the homepage.

Is there any way for it to just remove the www. from the page they are looking for then redirect them to that page instead of the homepage?

Comment: is www.example.com/example is real page and it exists?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `$1` to the URL you redirect to, to capture the bracketed part in `RewriteRule ^(.*)$` (i.e. the trailing `example`). I think something like this should do it:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: So: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [R=301,QSA,NC,L]